# Is an AST enough to build any translator?

Tags: compiler, grammar

*Note: In my ignorance of the difference between Programmers vs StackOverflow sites (which I know now), I had posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688892/ast-is-it-enough-to-build-any-translator) on StackOverflow earlier. What I'm looking for is some elaboration, for example, on the comment by Gene.*

---

Once I am able to build an abstract syntax tree (AST) for an input, then:

1. regardless of the type of the grammar used for building the AST (LR, LL*, or even no formal grammar as with Perl 5);
2. regardless of the parser-generator used for building the AST (`bison`, `antlr`, or my own hand-written code); and
3. regardless of the number of passes I do over my input for building the AST;

... **is it true** that I can implement **any** feature of **any** language ever created just by visiting the AST `N` number of times?

I'm not worried about the complexity of the resulting code, or its performance, I just need to know whether an AST is sufficient to allow the building of a translator (a compiler or an interpreter) regardless of the feature I am trying to build.

I am not looking for an exhaustive list of what cannot be done with an AST, just 1 example should suffice. If an AST is a sufficiently fundamental (and thus versatile/powerful) structure to allow the building of just about any translator, then a I'd like to see a confirmation of this fact. Getting the source of the book or a URL (if one exists) would be an additional bonus.

Just as an AST, being a tree, would be more powerful data structure than (and, thus, can also emulate) a flat or linear intermediate representation (IR) such as the Three-Address Code as covered in the Dragon book, so also an abstract syntax graph (*ASG*, if you will), being a graph, would be more powerful than an AST. Thus, elaborating further on my original post: **Is there any translator feature known to mankind as of this writing that cannot be implemented by an AST and requires the use of an ASG?**

Comment: Gene's comment is still valid here: *the question you are asking is too vague to be meaningfully answerable.*  If you need clarification on something Gene said in his comment, focus on that thing specifically in your question.  Or, simply ask Gene what he meant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But please do see my predicament: I cannot go through a whole plethora of books to find out what an AST **cannot** do. Also, isn't this a "whiteboard" type of question...? where, a programmer would propose to build an AST for a translator claiming that just about **any** translator could be built once an AST is there, and the others would counter that with at least 1 example. I don't see how my question is vague.

Comment: I want to move to a new town. Please tell me what that new town *cannot* provide me.

Comment: On a town-moving help site, that would be a perfectly legit question - especially when people have already gone through the process and have a not-necessarily-complete list of examples of what the new town does not provide.

Comment: It's a question alright.  But how do you answer it in any meaningful way?

Comment: By giving at least 1 example?

Comment: Uh, no.  That's not the question you asked.  If that's the question you really wanted to ask, now you have a way to make it more specific.  Perhaps you meant *counter-example?*  Because then you would only need one such counter-example to disprove **any**.

Comment: Added an EDIT section to (hopefully) address that. I'm new to compilers AND to this group as well.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  Also check out  [Why was my question closed as too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)

Comment: If the AST doesn't suffice on its own, what prevents you from bringing additional tools to bear on the problem?

Comment: Any software can be fixed and even completely rewritten as you go along developing it. Then, why have software forums at all? Why even have books when we can always learn things first-hand, from scratch, on the fly, in our own little hole, cut-off from the rest of the world?

Comment: Perhaps a more straightforward way to explain the problem is that you'd have to rigorously define "translator" or "feature" for this to be answerable. For instance, typically I'd assume an AST does not include comments, line numbers, whitespace, file names, etc. Any "feature" relying on those aspects of the source code obviously can't be done with the AST. But maybe your ASTs include those things, or maybe you wouldn't consider special annotations in comments to be "features of the language". We just don't know.

Comment: An AST can represent an arbitrary amount of information about the source file, up to an including "all of it". As such, the answer is clearly "yes". The only real question is how much of the information in the original source is needed to translate a particular language. Usually you preserve more than is strictly necessary for translation, to support producing better error messages.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thanks for that helpful confirmation.

Comment: @Ixrec The dragon book, I believe, defines a translator as either a compiler or an interpreter - I don't know if there's a rigorous definition for it, or even what constitutes a rigorous definition except for maybe popular citations. Regarding your example of comments, whitespace, filenames etc, you again commit the fallacy of saying that an AST not including x, y, and z cannot support (features relying on) x, y, and z - how could it?! That would be an AST that is simply discarding a subset of information in the source language, and so, how could it deal with such discarded information?!

Comment: @Harry That's a tautology, not a fallacy. Part of the point is the only way to answer your question is with tautologies like that. It is *possible* to do X with an AST as long as X only requires stuff contained in the AST. So the only things you can't do with an AST are the ones that require information the AST does not preserve. Any answer more useful/interesting than that would require more specific definitions; otherwise you could just redefine your ASTs so that they do include whitespace or whatever.

Comment: @Ixrec I can understand inadvertent tautologies that sometimes creep in our communication, ones that aren't immediately obvious. But why would you knowingly answer a genuine question with a tautology without even forewarning the reader? I completely disagree that a tautology is the 'only' way to answer this, or in fact any question. My original post was only about seeking >= 1 example(s) of **"the only things you can't do with an AST"**. And if there were really no such things, you could've simply stated so, just like JerryCoffin did.

Comment: @Ixrec The 3-address-code code-generation (as covered in the dragon book), e.g., would flatten the tree structure implicit in the input language, making it impossible to reconstruct the original, basic structure of the input (say, in a reverse engineering use-case). My original post wanted to seek only such example(s) of things that would not be possible with an AST, if at all they existed; I intuitively knew they didn't but still wanted to get some sort of a confirmation/denial from folks with more experience in building translators with or without ASTs.

Comment: Are you asking about any particular AST structure, or the concept of ASTs in general? You will not have much luck implementing monads in a Brainfuck AST.

Comment: @immibis General ASTs, as opposed to something like the Three Address Code in the style of the Dragon-book. Please see the EDIT towards the end of my original post that I'm about to add right about now... as soon as I finish typing this comment.

Comment: So you're actually asking whether there any translations that can't easily be done from an AST that can be easily done from a more advanced structure? Key word "easily" - you *can* do anything you want with an AST, or even with a flat list of instructions.

Comment: Saw your edit.  I'm amused that you still think we're omnipotent enough to answer such a question definitively.  I'm especially intrigued by your use of the words "known to mankind."

Comment: @immibis Yes, that's what I am and have been asking. I cannot believe my original post was so inscrutable so as to have taken this long to elicit a helpful answer, however short. +1. If you or Jerry Coffin could re-write your comment as an answer, I'll be more than happy to select that as the final answer that really has appealed to me so far.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've little doubt in my mind by this point that all you and your friends have been doing so far is pure nit-picking, or even bullying a newbie, given the 100K+ reputation you have, on a weekend with probably nothing constructive to do. In any case, I got what I wanted from 2 very polite and helpful users, each with a fraction of your reputation. Thank you very much, now you can downvote and close my question all you want. Goodbye.

Comment: @JerryCoffin If you can type your comment as an answer, I'd consider making that final. But hurry you must, for adverse forces are at work here and they may close the question before long.

Comment: @Harry: The question's been closed for ~15 hours already...

Comment: @JerryCoffin It's says "on hold", and not "[closed]". They are still giving me a chance to rephrase my question to make it acceptable to their false egos. If it were closed, we wouldn't be able to post any comment (I think)!

Comment: Regardless of the name used, nobody can enter new answers to it right now. Comments can be posted until/unless it's deleted.

Comment: I see! (Too bad!) Well thanks for your willingness to help, AND actual help, bro!

Comment: Sufficiently privileged users can vote to reopen a question if they feel it's been clarified enough. (I have that level of privilege on SO, but not here) By the way, "on hold" and "closed" mean exactly the same thing, as far as I know. *"Closed" was changed to "on hold"* because they thought "closed" sounded more irreversible than that status actually is.

Comment: I think "is it true that I can implement any feature of any language ever created just by visiting the AST N number of times?" still makes it sound like you can't modify the AST structure. You **cannot** translate lambda expressions from a Java 7 AST, because Java 7 ASTs can't represent lambda expressions in the first place! But if you can modify the structure of your ASTs then you could add support for lambda expressions.

Comment: @immibis I'm open to modification, decoration, annotation, etc of the AST as long as the 'tree' need not have to be upgraded to the next level of data-structure in complexity and power (such as a graph). I clarified this only in my EDITs later. So, flat/linear structure versus tree versus graph vs something else more powerful than a graph (if there is one)!

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, yes, assuming you have an AST for a Turing Complete language. It may mean interpreting `a+b` as something not meaning "add the variables referenced by these two identifiers together", or building your own compiler in the source language to implement the feature, or something else particularly *impractical*. But once you can model one Turing Complete language, you can do whatever you want.

*Practically* though, no. If your source language (and AST) has no concept of *functions*, then it may be tricky to implement them as a feature just by AST translations. Could you do it in the source language? Sure. Could you add AST nodes to support it? Sure. Those are pretty easy.

But changing the meaning of the syntax nodes in any coherent way gets a lot more (order of magnitude+) difficult.

Comment: If my *"source language (and AST) has no concept of functions"*, then why would I want to *"implement them as a feature"*?

Comment: @harry - damned if I know, you're the one that asked the question.

Comment: Maybe, your response lacks clarity?

Comment: @Harry: Huh? Your comments make no sense whatsoever. In your question, you ask "Can I", now in your comments all of a sudden you ask "Why would I want to?" Well, we don't know why you would want to. You just say in your question that you *do* want to, and we take that as a given. (More precisely: you ask "Can I?" which implies that you do want to, because otherwise why would you ask in the first place?)

Comment: It's like asking a waiter at the restaurant "Can I have ketchup with my steak", then the waiter replies "No, you cannot have ketchup with your steak" and then you yell at him "Why would I want to have ketchup with my steak?" Well, you asked about having ketchup with your steak, so, it's reasonable assumption that you weren't just compiling a database of possible condiments but actually *wanted* to have ketchup with your steak.

Comment: @Telastyn, the question now is - why do we need functions for Turing completeness.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I am amazed at the level of comprehension you seem to share with Telastyn! If I wanted to have functions in my source language, SURELY I'd account for them in my AST with appropriate function-type nodes. Obviously, if I don't account for them with the appropriate function-type nodes, I WON'T be able to realize functions. When Telastyn prefixes his sentence with **"If your source language (AST) has no concept of functions, then..."**, he confuses me and probably other readers too. Better wording would have been: An AST is (or is not) capable of supporting functions.

Comment: Obviously, an AST **can** trivially support functions. The intent of my  original post was (and even is) to get some examples of things that an AST by itself won't allow me to do. Because I'm not experienced enough in building translators, I thought I'd post to this group and hope to get some insightful examples of things people **already** know that an AST cannot support, where I would deadend in my choice of AST as fundamental structure of my translator, etc.

Comment: The dragon book, for example, mentions in the chapter on CFGs, that a CFG cannot help with function declaration preceding a function definition/invocation for which one would require help of a symbol table. Likewise, I want(ed) to know some examples of what an AST cannot achieve. Maybe, it can achieve everything being a fundamental tree structure. But THAT is something I did/do not know for sure - which is why I posted the question in the first place.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Your waiter example is grossly specious. I ask the waiter for examples of things I cannot have with my steak. The waiter either lists them all, or gives some examples of things I cannot have, or says that there's nothing I cannot have with my steak! But your style of waiter says, "If you don't want to have ketchup with your steak, then you cannot have ketchup with your stake!" Telastyn's waiter says, "If you don't want to have ketchup with your steak, then it can be tricky to bring you ketchup with your steak!"

Comment: @Harry - `some examples of things that an AST by itself won't allow me to do` - and that is my answer - If you have an AST of a Turing Complete language, there is _nothing_ that the AST by itself won't allow you to do. You can translate that to do _literally_ any compute-able problem (with enough processing of it).